# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" при вызове session start()

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   Z:\home\test1.ru\www\ok\reg.php on line 2

[Код на pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wEPtXmKY):

```
<?php
session start();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Да, я уже нашел это. 
Теперь выдаёт:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\ok\reg.php on line 52
Поправленый код тут:
http://pastebin.com/pBNQ1aTX

Comment: Что-то забыли закрыть, проверяйте весь код

Comment: Одной скобки не хватало.

Comment: @Radiance, учитесь форматировать исходники и пользоваться нормальными редакторами/IDE. Если привести вашу мешанину к читаемому виду, станет очевидно, что пропущена одна закрывающая фигурная скобка.